# Spinner style and databinding

Tags: android, data-binding, android-spinner, android-databinding

I wanna change the style of my spinner (make a bigger text and align it to the centre).

Usually, I created layout file spinner_item.xm

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:gravity="center" />
```

And change the declaration of the spinner:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.planets_array, R.layout.spinner_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

However, how should I achieve that when I'm using databinding.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you're using a xml file as adapter, so you have a `TextView` under the xml, you can try to change the property `android:textSize` to a value above the current and the property `android:textAlignment` to center.

Example:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: yes, but where should I setAdapter when I'm using databinding?